# FCKeditor is not working with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, fckeditor

I am new to Codeigniter. I am developing an application; for that I need to integrate FCKEditor with codeigniter. I tried it but it is not working. I am getting the an error like this - please help me. I tried as said in http://bagoesseptian.blogspot.in/2009/07/make-fckeditor-plugin-in-codeigniter.html

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$Fckeditor
Filename: admin/events.php
Line Number: 5
Fatal error: Call to a member function Create() on a non-object
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of your `admin/events.php` file? Looks like you are having a problem loading the library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got solution from the below link http://webroxtar.com/2011/11/how-to-use-fck-editor-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seems to be a good way. Try this way:
Steps:
1.Download CKEditor from http://ckeditor.com/download
2.unzip it in index directory of codeigniter
3.Use this syntax in header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

4.Use this in body where you want to place editor:

```
<textarea name="n_notification" id="n_notification"></textarea>
```

5.Use this to initiate:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'n_notification');
}
</script>
```

You can refer http://dwij.co.in/ckeditor-ckfinder-integration-using-php/ to integrate CKEditor with CKFinder(File Browser) if you want image uploader.